# Google Calendar API - Error 400 Request Invalid - Loopback - Flutter App

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I was was originally using the [googleapis_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth) package in our Flutter app to redirect to the browser, have user sign in to their Google account and retrieve credentials with which we would access the Calendar API.

I received a 400 Error stating the app made an invalid request to Google's servers.

[image: 400 Error Message]

[image: Loopback Error]

I migrated to [google_sign_in package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) as was recommended online.

Then I get the following error

`PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)`

Upon searching online I found that the most common cause of this exception is incorrect SHA-1 certificate fingerprint when setting up the OAuth Credentials. I verified that this is correct and I still get the error.

Another cause I suspect could be is that the OAuth Consent Screen is still pending approval.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm stuck at the same issue.

Comment: Same issue. Let us know if you resolve this!

Comment: Not yet. Issue still persist

Comment: @RohitRao  Facing the same issue. Let us know if you resolve this! –